# C++ back_insert_iterator for Container-Adapters

Tags: c++

The C++ iterator library contains the [back_insert_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator) which is an output-iterator calling `push_back`on its container. I can use it together with containers like `vector`, `deque`or `list`which makes the usage of algorithms like `std::copy`quite handy. Now I wanted to use a [queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) which does not have a function `push_back` but only a function `push`. I am wondering:

1. Why is the member function called `push` and not `push_back`?
2. If it is named `push`, why not provide a specialized `back_insert_iterator`for `queue`?

Comment: Why the "language-lawyer" tag?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: On the one hand, this question is not about how to fix it; it's about why they are this way. So it's not really a duplicate of that question. On the other hand, such questions are of dubious merit, so I'm inclined to leave it closed.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk because I am interested about this topic from a C++-standard point of view. If there is not a good reason why the function is called push and not push_back I would suggest to write a proposal to add the function push_back to the container-adapter. But I hope that there are good reasons and I want to know and understand them.

Comment: A queue is always one direction. The queue pushes the elements on the back of the underlying container and pops them from the front. So actually push_back, do not make any meaning for queue. So obviously back_insert_iterator  too.

Comment: @Kilian: "*because I am interested about this topic from a C++-standard point of view.*" The language-lawyer tag is for questions about what the specification says, not *why* the specification says it. The specification details what is C++; it doesn't go into issues of why C++ is the way it is.